# Get percentile points from a huge list

Tags: python

I have a huge list (45M+ data poitns), with numerical values: 
[78,0,5,150,9000,5,......,25,9,78422...]

I can easily get the maximum and minimum values, the number of these values, and the sum of them:

```
file_handle=open('huge_data_file.txt','r')
sum_values=0
min_value=None
max_value=None

for i,line in enumerate(file_handle):
    value=int(line[:-1])
    if min_value==None or value<min_value:
        min_value=value
    if max_value==None or value>max_value:
        max_value=value
    sum_values+=value
average_value=float(sum_values)/i
```

However, this is not what I need. I need a list of 10 numbers, where the number of data points between each two consecutive points is equal, for example

median points [0,30,120,325,912,1570,2522,5002,7025,78422]
and we have the number of data points between 0 and 30 or between 30 and 120 to be almost 4.5 million data points.
How can we do this?

=============================

## EDIT:

I am well aware that we will need to sort the data. The problem is that I cannot fit all this data in one variable in memory, but I need to read it sequentially from a generator (file_handle)

Comment: Sort the data set first, and your problem becomes a lot easier.

Comment: You're looking for percentiles right, not "the" median? You could sort and then just select first, 450,000 etc values in the list.

Comment: of course, but how would I sort data of such magnitude?

Comment: How much memory has your computer got?

Comment: sorting 45 million values is no problem at all (numpy array goes in 3 seconds)

Comment: You might want to look at numpy, does numpy.partition do what you want? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy.partition Edit: no, that one does a copy, I guess you'll want to use numpy.percentile http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#numpy.percentile

Comment: Here are some suggestions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: Guys, I need a scalable solution, cannot depend on much memory I have because I can easily get bigger lists

Comment: Dude, you need to sort anyway if you plan to get the median (unless you want to predict it, but that's a completely different story). how do you think any "median" function knows it is the middle value, hint: some sorting involved?

Comment: yup, sorting it is, but how to do this in python with such a huge list?

Comment: just "sorted" on such a list completed within a minute. if you convert the list first to numpy, the sorting will happen in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with an approximation, here is a great (and fairly easy to implement) algorithm for computing quantiles from stream data: ["Space-Efficient Online Computation of Quantile Summaries"](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~datar/courses/cs361a/papers/quantiles.pdf) by Greenwald and Khanna.

Comment: Any idea if this is implemented in python?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know of any open source Python implementations. However, the algorithm is fairly easy to implement (I've done it in the past) and works really, really well.

Comment: You should post it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The silly numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

# example data (produced by numpy but converted to a simple list)
datalist = list(np.random.randint(0, 10000000, 45000000))

# converted back to numpy array (start here with your data)
arr = np.array(datalist)
np.percentile(arr, 10), np.percentile(arr, 20), np.percentile(arr, 30)
# ref: 
# http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html
```

You can also hack something together where you just do like:

```
arr.sort()

# And then select the 10%, 20% etc value, add some check for equal amount of
# numbers within a bin and then calculate the average, excercise for reader :-)
```

The thing is that calling this function several times will slow it down, so really, just sort the array and then select the elements yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot just fit the entire list in memory like that, I need to read it item by item from a generator (file handle).

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments that you want a solution that can scale to larger datasets then can be stored in RAM, feed the data into an SQLlite3 database. Even if your data set is 10GB and you only have 8GB RAM a SQLlite3 database should still be able to sort the data and give it back to you in order.

The SQLlite3 database gives you a generator over your sorted data.
You might also want to look into going beyond python and take some other database solution.

Comment: I like this idea, but still prefer a pure python solution if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure-python implementation of the partitioned-on-disk sort. It's slow, ugly code, but it works and hopefully each stage is relatively clear (the merge stage is really ugly!).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os


def get_next_int_from_file(f):
    l = f.readline()
    if not l:
        return None
    return int(l.strip())


MAX_SAMPLES_PER_PARTITION = 1000000
PARTITION_FILENAME = "_{}.txt"

# Partition data set
part_id = 0
eof = False

with open("data.txt", "r") as fin:
    while not eof:
        print "Creating partition {}".format(part_id)
        with open(PARTITION_FILENAME.format(part_id), "w") as fout:
            for _ in range(MAX_SAMPLES_PER_PARTITION):
                line = fin.readline()
                if not line:
                    eof = True
                    break
                fout.write(line)
        part_id += 1

num_partitions = part_id


# Sort each partition
for part_id in range(num_partitions):
    print "Reading unsorted partition {}".format(part_id)
    with open(PARTITION_FILENAME.format(part_id), "r") as fin:
        samples = [int(line.strip()) for line in fin.readlines()]
    print "Disk-Deleting unsorted {}".format(part_id)
    os.remove(PARTITION_FILENAME.format(part_id))
    print "In-memory sorting partition {}".format(part_id)
    samples.sort()
    print "Writing sorted partition {}".format(part_id)
    with open(PARTITION_FILENAME.format(part_id), "w") as fout:
        fout.writelines(["{}\n".format(sample) for sample in samples])


# Merge-sort the partitions
# NB This is a very inefficient implementation!
print "Merging sorted partitions"
part_files = []
part_next_int = []
num_lines_out = 0

# Setup data structures for the merge
for part_id in range(num_partitions):
    fin = open(PARTITION_FILENAME.format(part_id), "r")
    next_int = get_next_int_from_file(fin)
    if next_int is None:
        continue
    part_files.append(fin)
    part_next_int.append(next_int)

with open("data_sorted.txt", "w") as fout:
    while part_files:
        # Find the smallest number across all files
        min_number = None
        min_idx = None
        for idx in range(len(part_files)):
            if min_number is None or part_next_int[idx] < min_number:
                min_number = part_next_int[idx]
                min_idx = idx
        # Now add that number, and move the relevent file along
        fout.write("{}\n".format(min_number))
        num_lines_out += 1
        if num_lines_out % MAX_SAMPLES_PER_PARTITION == 0:
            print "Merged samples: {}".format(num_lines_out)

        next_int = get_next_int_from_file(part_files[min_idx])
        if next_int is None:
            # Remove this partition, it's now finished
            del part_files[min_idx:min_idx + 1]
            del part_next_int[min_idx:min_idx + 1]
        else:
            part_next_int[min_idx] = next_int

# Cleanup partition files
for part_id in range(num_partitions):
    os.remove(PARTITION_FILENAME.format(part_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

My code a proposal for finding the result without needing much space. In testing it found a quantile value in 7 minutes 51 seconds for a dataset of size 45 000 000.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class data():
    def __init__(self, values):
        random.shuffle(values)
        self.values = values
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.values:
            yield i
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.values)
    def sortedValue(self, percentile):
        val = list(self)
        val.sort()
        num = int(len(self)*percentile)
        return val[num]

def init():
    numbers = data([x for x in range(1,1000000)])
    print(seekPercentile(numbers, 0.1))
    print(numbers.sortedValue(0.1))


def seekPercentile(numbers, percentile):
    lower, upper = minmax(numbers)
    maximum = upper
    approx = _approxPercentile(numbers, lower, upper, percentile)
    return neighbor(approx, numbers, maximum)

def minmax(list):
    minimum = float("inf")
    maximum = float("-inf")

    for num in list:
        if num>maximum:
            maximum = num
        if num<minimum:
            minimum = num
    return minimum, maximum

def neighbor(approx, numbers, maximum):
    dif = maximum
    for num in numbers:
        if abs(approx-num)<dif:
            result = num
            dif = abs(approx-num)
    return result

def _approxPercentile(numbers, lower, upper, percentile):
    middles = []
    less = []
    magicNumber = 10000
    step = (upper - lower)/magicNumber
    less = []
    for i in range(1, magicNumber-1):
        middles.append(lower + i * step)
        less.append(0)

    for num in numbers:
        index = bisect_left(middles,num)
        if index<len(less):
            less[index]+= 1

    summing = 0
    for index, testVal in enumerate(middles):
        summing += less[index]
        if summing/len(numbers) < percentile:
            print(" Change lower from "+str(lower)+" to "+ str(testVal))
            lower = testVal

        if summing/len(numbers) > percentile:
            print(" Change upper from "+str(upper)+" to "+ str(testVal))
            upper = testVal
            break


    precision = 0.01
    if (lower+precision)>upper:
        return lower
    else:
        return _approxPercentile(numbers, lower, upper, percentile)

init()
```

I edited my code a bit and I now think that this way works at least decently even when it's not optimal.

Comment: I believe the OP's problem isn't reading data from disk, it's storing all the numbers simultaneously in memory.

Comment: @Tom Dalton My code solves the problem of the OP without storing data in memory.

Comment: `numbers = [random.random()*x for x in range(1,45000000)]` says that's not true - you're storing all the numbers is a single list (in memory!).

Comment: @Tom Dalton: My algorithm doesn't depend on having the variable in memory. Numbers doesn't need to be a list. It just needs to implement __len__() and return a generator when you call it.

Comment: I'd be happy for you to demonstrate that with some code! At the moment it does rely on that for the `min()` and `max()`, not to mention that it actually *does* store the data set in memory.

Comment: @Tom Dalton : min() and max() can be called on a generator. If you would read the OP he actually says that he knows how to get min and max from his dataset. It makes no sense to write in my answer a min and a max function.

Comment: All I am saying is that, given the OP's problem is that he can't store the dataset in memory, providing an example that does store the dataset in memory isn't that useful.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't work with generators: `a = (i for i in range(5));min(a);max(a);` -> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: Then I think the easiest way to resolve this would be for you to post a version that does actually do that!

Comment: So, I added the boilerplate needed to fulfill your demands, but that code isn't central to the question. My coded isn't intended to be used as is but to demonstrate an algorithm. Your can probably speed it up by 100x or more for solving the target problem but that makes the code more complex.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. The data class is broken. I understand what you're saying, but maybe you would be better to give the solution in pseudocode if that's your intention.